# FreeNAS ufs root fs bad, recover freenas-v1.db

Tags: truenas, fsck, ufs

I'm booting my FreeNAS from an USB stick. But it became bad and won't boot up.

```
bad dir ino {X} at offset {X}: mangled entry
```

I now attached the USB drive to a VM with FreeNAS to mount / or repair the fs on the stick with fsck.

After running `fsck -y -t ufs` once, the partition seems to be totally destroyed (can't even rerun fsck as it just gives "`no superblock found`"). So I guess the fs can't be repaired.

That's why I'm now trying to retrieve the config `/data/freenas-v1.db`.

I mounted "`mount -t ufs /dev/da0s1a /tmp/test`" but "`ls /tmp/test/data/`" just gives:

```
ls: zfs: Bad file descriptor
./ ../
```

In a working install the config file `freenas-v1.db` is within that folder and `zfs` is an ordinary subdir of the folder.

Is the file lost? Any chance to get it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the file. Didn't realized /data is mounted from the 4th partition and is not part of the root filesystem.

Unfortunately, it's corrupted and can't be opened and sqlite doesn't seem to have a good tool to repair corrupted databases. So I'm finally out of luck with this.